# HTML JavaScript dropdown onChange not triggered

Tags: javascript, html

I started with the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/U4vaP/4/

This is the HTML

```
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
<select id="mycars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

This is the Javascript

```
$("#next").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mycars > option:selected').next('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mycars > option:selected').prev('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

Then I added this onChange event listener to trigger a function in javascript

```
<select id="mycars" onChange="showModel(this.value)">
```

The function is triggered when you select a make from the dropdown list directly, but when you use the **Next** and **Previous** buttons, it doesn't trigger "showModel(this.value)". How do you make it recognize the change?

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to be functioning just fine, can you add the parts that don't seem to be working as I have nothing to debug.... Include `showModel()` as that function is relevant to your question.

Comment: Just use any simple function. function showModel(a) {
    return a; 
}

Comment: Without seeing your intentions of `showModel()` I have created a demo for you. I'm not 100% sure if that is what you're looking for but from the way I read your question that seem to solve your problem. If this isn't what you're looking for please explain more and I will update/add/edit the answer below to fit.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see much use of creating a function `showModel()` since you already have jQuery at use I thought it would be much easier to have that deal with changes for your select element.

I have added jQuery's on `change` event handler to the select to alert the value but I have also added a trigger in each `next` and `prev` functions to execute the function for on change of `mycars`.

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/upr2g71t/)

> **Snippet Demo**

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mycars > option:selected').next('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  //Trigger onchange event
  $("#mycars").trigger("change");
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mycars > option:selected').prev('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  //Trigger onchange event
  $("#mycars").trigger("change");
});
// On change event for the select. 
$("#mycars").on('change', function() {
  $('#selection').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selection">Please make a selection...</div>

<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
<select id="mycars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!